# Can you explain this substitution rule?

Tags: replacement, pattern-matching

This rule behaves as I expect:

```
b . c + a . b . c /. (b . c) -> x
(* x + a . x *)
```

I would expect the same result with this:

```
b . c + a . b . c /. (b . c | c . b) -> x
(* x + a . b . c *)
```

Can you explain why I am wrong?
(I know the brackets are redundant, but they make it a little easier to read)

EDIT

As @Syed suggests, there are simple ways of fixing the problem e.g.

```
b . c + a . b . c /. y___ . b . c :> y . x
(* x + a . x *)
```

However, to avoid difficulties in debugging complex sets of replacement rules, it's better to avoid these problems, rather than fix them afterwards.  How should I have known that my rule wouldn't work?

FURTHER EDIT

This effect is not specific to `Dot`, but appears to apply generally to functions with the attribute `Flat`.  For example, with

```
SetAttributes[g, Flat]
```

a simple pattern matches:

```
g[b, c] + g[a, b, c, d] /. g[b, c] -> x
(* x + g[a, x, d] *)
```

while alternatives do not:

```
g[b, c] + g[a, b, c, d] /. g[b, c] | g[c, b] -> x
(* x + g[a, b, c, d] *)
```

Is this behaviour documented anywhere?

Comment: `b . c + a . b . c /. y___ . b . c -> y . x` ?

Comment: You use `c.b` but this wouldn't match with anything in the expression, so please clarify and include more examples, if possible.

Comment: @Syed in my real example, I defined a large set of rules, which I applied (repeatedly) to multiple complex expressions.  For example, `c` was the matrix inverse of `b` and `x` was the identity matrix.  Obviously, this means that `b.c==c.b==x`.  The challenge is to define a set of rules that does exactly what is required.

Comment: I do not know what the alternative does not work. It looks like a bug to me. But you can replace the alternative by 2 Re[placeAll like:  `a1 . b . c + a2 . c . b /. b . c -> x /. c . b -> x` This results in: `a1 . x + a2 . x`

Comment: In addition, `Replace[b . c + a . b . c,(b . c | c . b) -> x,{1}]==Replace[b . c + a . b . c,(b . c  -> x),{1}]==(b . c + a . b . c /. (b . c | c . b) -> x)`   (*True*)

Comment: So why does `(a . b . c /. (b . c ) -> x)` replace, whereas `(a . b . c /. (b . c | c . b) -> x)` doesn't, and neither does `Replace[ a . b . c, (b . c  -> x),{1}]` ( nor `Replace[ a . b . c, (b . c | c . b) -> x,{1}]`)?

Comment: Using Dispatch may be another alternative: `b . c + a . b . c + d . c . b /. Dispatch[{b . c | c . b -> x}]` gives `(* x + a . x + d . x *)`

Answer (score 0):

Its simply so, that Alternatives are not identified a subsequences

```
     Position[b . c + a . b . c, (b . c | c . b), \[Infinity]]
        
       {{1}}

     Position[ b . c + a . b . c, (b . c | c . b | ___ . b . c . ___),
             \[Infinity]]

       {{1}, {2}}
```

The reason for this behaviour: sequences are not considered as expressions. Even in this simple case its a complex task to identify the position of a pair inside an argument sequence.

The logical decision for this behaviour is to avoid, generally, modifications to the right of inner leafs of a tree and to limit the search tree depth in normal cases, where only algebraic parts of an expression are renamed.

Reorganizing argument sequences is not a branch of mathematics but a kind of string manipulation, the reason why natural languages are more powerful but slightly less logical than mathematics.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. What's matched here is not sequence. Please read the first example in the question carefully. `Dot` (`.`) behaves like this because it owns the attribute `Flat`.

Comment: No, try $$a\cdot b\cdot c\text{/.}\, b\cdot c|c\cdot b\to x$$  with no attributes. Subsequence not identified.

Comment: Once again, please check the behavior of first example i.e. `b . c + a . b . c /. (b . c) -> x
(* returns x + a . x *)` carefully. With `·` (`\[CenterDot]`), the first example won't "work", either: `b·c + a·b·c /. b·c -> x (*returns x + a·b·c *)`

Comment: If you're not familiar with the attribute `Flat`, check e.g. http://www.verbeia.com/mathematica/tips/Tricks.html (The notebook version is here: https://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/4557/ )

Comment: I am familiar with anything since the first attemtps of Wolfram, sorry.  The Replace actions were always full of surprises, bomb shells and shutdowns and students in despair. This is not very different from the methods  used by mathematicians and physicists with pencil and paper.  Its not worth the work to identify the rules, that are not documented and not constant over versions, Use clear Patterns and nothing open to interpretation.